# Reference to a 'haunted asteroid' in Rendezvous with Rama

Tags: story-identification, arthur-c-clarke, reference, rendezvous-with-rama

In *Rendezvous with Rama*, Commander Bill Norton makes the following comment:

> “The Haunted Asteroid”: why had that phrase popped up from the depths of memory? Then he recalled a silly story he had read years ago, but thought it best not to ask Rodrigo if he had ever seen it. He doubted if the other’s tastes ran to that sort of reading.

I've found three references to what this story ***might*** be:

1. Donald A. Wollheim's *Asteroid 745: Mauritia* (1953)
2. Henry Kuttner's *What Hath Me?* (1946)
3. Arnold Drake's 'Haunted Asteroid'(1977) *The Enterprise Logs* #3 (Gold Key Comics reprint)

However, I have not been able to find what Clarke was referring to specifically.

Anyone know..?

Comment: Surely Kuttner's story is not from 2016. Ah, 1946, edited.

Comment: Another to add to the list of possibilities - Murray Leinster's 'The Wailing Asteroid'

Comment: The Gold Key comics seems unlikely unless Clarke had a time machine.  RwR is from 1973.

Comment: It might have been a roundabout reference to Clarke's story _Who's There_, aka _The Haunted Space Suit_.

Comment: Organic Marble: thanks for the correction/edit: my bad (I took the Kindle e-book re-release date: oops). The Gold Key comic (I listed the reprint date) is from June 1973 one month before Clarke's novel was published, so it's possible (I doubt it, too; but, it is possible).

Comment: user14111, Martin Goldsack, & Kenster: thanks for these new leads.. More cool stories to read that I didn't know about (forgot about the Bradbury one!). Even if they turn out not to be the ones Norton is referring to I'll enjoy checking them out--thanks! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Probably Ray Bradbury's *Asleep In Armageddon*. Afaik that's by far the best-known one on such a theme.

The central character is haunted by the ghosts of two leaders of opposing sides in the war which destroyed the planet from which the Asteroids were formed. They both want control of his body, and fight for it in his mind. He doesn't dare sleep due to the nightmares this produces.